# Bash: How to lock also when perform an outside script

Tags: bash, flock

Here is my bash code:

```
(
flock -n -e 200 || (echo "This script is currently being run" && exit 1)
    sleep 10

    ...Call some functions which is written in another script...

    sleep 5

) 200>/tmp/blah.lockfile
```

I'm running the script from two shells successively and as long as the first one is at "sleep 5" all goes good, meaning that the other one doesn't start. But when the first turns to perform the code from another script (other file) the second run starts to execute.

So I have two questions here:

1. What should I do to prevent this script and all its "children" from run while the script OR its "child" is still running. 
   (I didn't find a more appropriate expression for running another script other than a "child", sorry for that :) ).
2. According to man page, -n causes the process to exit when it fails to gain the lock, but as far as I can see it just wait until it can run. What am I missing ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your problem may be fairly mundane.  Namely,

```
false || ( exit 1 )
```

Does not cause the script to exit.  Rather, the exit instructs the subshell to exit.  So change your first line to:

```
flock -n -e 200 || { echo "This script is currently being run"; exit 1; } >&2
```

Comment: The answer by William is correct.
However, if you have to use a subshell, then you will need to kill parent of subshell using `kill` command. To get parent shell's PID, you can use `ps -p $$ -oppid=`. However, his answer is cleaner solution.

Comment: @anishsane both `bash`, `ksh` and `dash` have a `$PPID` variable for that matter. Don't know if it's really standard, but seems to be very compatible, and you don't fork an extra process.

Comment: Oh, I've missed this point at all. But something that I didn't realize: you change only one line, so your implementation uses a sub-shell as well, so how do you get over that problem you described. (I tried it and it worked, I'm curious how is it). In fact I didn't  fully understand why was sub-shell suggested by the man page, and why doesn't it work for me without creating a sub-shell (I'm getting an error that "200 is a bad file-descriptor"). Thanks.

Comment: The difference is that I use `{}` rather than `()`.  Commands in parentheses run in a subshell, but commands grouped by brackets run in the current shell.  You don't need to run your full process in a subshell either, but can use brackets instead to group the commands, but the `200>/tmp/lockfile` must apply to the call to flock, and if you just drop the grouping you'll get a `bad file descriptor` error.